# Vagrant+Puppet puppet.module_path not working

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

So I have my Vagrant file set up like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end
end
```

Now when I `vagrant ssh` into my VM and then run `puppet module install puppetlabs-apache`, i get the following error:

`Error: Could not install module 'puppetlabs-apache' (latest)
  Directory /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules does not exist`

So what I tried was:

`mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules`

followed by:

`puppet module install puppetlabs-apache`

and it worked!

But the module files are not showing up in my host machine under the `"modules"` directory that I set in my Vagrantfile. So I guess the `puppet.module_path` isn't working..?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried the same running `puppet module` as `root` instead of the `vagrant` user?

Comment: Yup. Then it says `/etc/puppet/modules` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `puppet` inside your VM is not the same as Puppet as it is used for provisioning from the host.

The Puppet resources that Vagrant uses are part of the Vagrant project. As you can see, the Puppet command inside the VM uses either

- local Puppet config and resources in `~/.puppet` or
- global resources in `/etc/puppet`

The Puppet configuration is not shared between host and VM.

Comment: Then how do I install puppet modules?

Comment: If you need modules during provisioning, you install them [in your vagrant project](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vagrant-up/zLCnqzCYckA/xAx27C3BfT4J). Once provisioning is complete, you can just use Puppet inside the VM. Required modules need to be installed there again.