# Puppet module install error - Directory /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules does not exist

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I've got puppet working (with Vagrant) with a few of my own simple modules but i'm running into difficulty when trying to install modules from puppet forge.

*VagrantFile:*

```rb
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 3000

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
  end

end
```

From inside my Virtual machine I am running:

> puppet module install akandels-phpunit

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not install module 'akandels-phpunit' (latest)
>
> Directory /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules does not exist

I've seen one answer to [Vagrant+Puppet puppet.module_path not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590651/vagrantpuppet-puppet-module-path-not-working) but it's not very clear.

I am using the basebox hashicorp/precise64 which is working fine with my own puppet modules.

What could be the problem here? Am I using puppet wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please note that the `puppet` instance that you configure through `Vagrantfile` is different from `puppet` invoked from the shell of the VM. With Vagrant, you usually want to put all your Puppet content into the Vagrant project, so that the manifest (including the modules you chose) are applied during provisioning. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: @FelixFrank so I don't run puppet module install [module name] from the command line inside the VM? My puppet content is in my Vagrant project, I want to be able to run the puppet module install command to install modules.

Comment: then you will have to run `puppet module install` from the host system. You need add parameters in order for `puppet` to use your Vagrant project as the module location. If I find time to try this, I will add an answer with more details.